# Cordova Android - Camera doesn't have all options

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am building an Android application using Cordova and cordova-plugin-camera.
From what I understand, this plugin will trigger native Camera of Android and will allow to make a photo that later can be used in Cordova app.

The problem that I have is that when camera is opened by Cordova, I am missing the other options that I have in native camera (night-vision, HDR, etc).

Here you can see what I mean:

This is how camera looks when I opened it from Android (notice "mai multe" button)
[image: This is how camera looks when I opened it from Android (notice "mai multe" button)]

And this is how camera looks when is opened by Cordova:

[image]

You can notice that the bottom menu is no longer there.

Can we do something to have this menu in Cordova? Because we want to take photos using different modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinkg this is default behavior of the Android Camera API. Your first screenshot shows the default camera app. But if you open the Camera with your app the Android camera API is used. I suspect it depends on your devices manifacturer to implement this.